# Rails 3.1 app cannot destroy mysql2 object

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails and i've created a web app to manage my warehouses.
I've the following problem: when I click on "destroy" button (see attached below), the related object isn't delate from mysql2 database. Anyone can help me?

This is controller

`

```
    class PositionsController < ApplicationController

       #before_filter :check_count, :only => [:destroy]

      # GET /positions
      # GET /positions.xml
      def index
        @positions = Position.find(:all)

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # index.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @positions }
        end
      end

      # GET /positions/1
      # GET /positions/1.xml
      def show
        @position = Position.find(params[:id])

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # show.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @position }
        end
      end

      # GET /positions/new
      # GET /positions/new.xml
      def new
        @position = Position.new

        respond_to do |format|
          format.html # new.html.erb
          format.xml  { render :xml => @position }
        end
      end

      # GET /positions/1/edit
      def edit
        @position = Position.find(params[:id])
      end

      # POST /positions
      # POST /positions.xml

  def create
    @position = Position.new(params[:position])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @position.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Position was successfully created.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@position) }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @position, :status => :created, :location => @position }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "new" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @position.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /positions/1
  # PUT /positions/1.xml
  def update
    @position = Position.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @position.update_attributes(params[:position])
        flash[:notice] = 'Position was successfully updated.'
        format.html { redirect_to(@position) }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      else
        format.html { render :action => "edit" }
        format.xml  { render :xml => @position.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /positions/1
  # DELETE /positions/1.xml
  def destroy
    @position = Position.find(params[:id])
    @position.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(positions_url) }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
  end

  private

  def check_count
     @position_to_destroy = Logicalwarehouse.find(params[:id])
     if @position_to_destroy.warehouse.count > 0
       flash[:notice] = "Non puoi cancellare una posizione in uso"
       redirect_to :positions
     end
   end
end
```

This is model

```
class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :warehouses
has_many :locks_on_warehouses, :class_name => "Warehouse", :foreign_key => "lock_by_position_id"
has_many :users
  belongs_to :registry
```

end

and this is view

```
    <h1>Listing positions</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
  </tr>

<% for position in @positions %>
  <tr>
    <td><%=h position.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', position %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_position_path(position) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', position, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New position', new_position_path %>
```

Other "actions" such as update,edit,show,index works fine but when I destroy an element, it doesn't give me any errors on web server console  but the element isn't removed from database.

Answer (score 1):

You've :

```
<td><%= link_to 'Destroy', position, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
```

At the end of the line replace `:method => :delete` by `:method => :destroy`

Comment: I've done that, but issue still remains! I've seen that I've the same issues for each controller and view that contains 'destroy' actions

Answer (score 1):

You havn't loaded `jquery-rails`. `DELETE` action is not supported by browsers, it's emulated by the `jquery-rails`.

Add this line to your Gemfile :

```
gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Assuming you are actually using jQuery!

The following is taken from the jquery-ujs script (https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/master/src/rails.js). If that is not present in your project, `DELETE` won't work :

```
// Handles "data-method" on links such as:
// <a href="/users/5" data-method="delete" rel="nofollow" data-confirm="Are you sure?">Delete</a>
handleMethod: function(link) {
  var href = link.attr('href'),
    method = link.data('method'),
    target = link.attr('target'),
    csrf_token = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content'),
    csrf_param = $('meta[name=csrf-param]').attr('content'),
    form = $('<form method="post" action="' + href + '"></form>'),
    metadata_input = '<input name="_method" value="' + method + '" type="hidden" />';

  if (csrf_param !== undefined && csrf_token !== undefined) {
    metadata_input += '<input name="' + csrf_param + '" value="' + csrf_token + '" type="hidden" />';
  }

  if (target) { form.attr('target', target); }

  form.hide().append(metadata_input).appendTo('body');
  form.submit();
},
```